# Nuxt : save fetch results for later use

Tags: nuxt.js

I am using this **fetch()** in a component (components/CategoriesSidebar.vue) :

```
export default {
    name: 'CategoriesSidebar',
    async fetch () {
            this.fetchresults = await this.$http.$get('https://domain/categories?json')
            this.categories = this.fetchresults.arraycategories
    },
}
```

The categories doesnt change often so is there a way to save the result so I dont fetch everytime the page is changing ?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057351/4523764 this will answer your question!

Comment: @HardikShah is session the clean way ? Isnt there something like "global" or "define" ?

Comment: as you can see there are multiple ways as per your needs you can select! IMO session good choice but depending on next user visit will data change for that component if not I will go for local storage or IndexedDB